# Accessing in code generated TextView Resource

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I have a little problem. I have a tool that will likly have a large an changing number of channels which should be displayed in an Layout. So I have to create the TextView for the displaying of the values in code. Which worked like a charm.

My problem:

1. How do I access the created "valueTV" Field in my Code? Specifically I want to write a Value of the accelerometer into it, which is stored in String SAccX.
2. Is there a method to see the created field with the R.id.XXX in the DDMS or Debug window of Eclipse?

If I try to access it with the assigning like an normal XML Object Eclipse gives me an error (something like " `sAccX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueTV201);` ). I understand why this error is coming up but I don't know how to get around it ;-)

```
    //Get Tablelayout 
    TableLayout ChannelTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableChannels);

    //Create a new Row for every Channel
    for (int current = 0; current < numberOfChannels; current++)
    {
        // Create a Table with new ID
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
        tr.setId(100 + current); 
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        // Create a TextView to show the Name of the Channel
        TextView TVChannels = new TextView(this); 
        TVChannels.setId(200 + current);
        TVChannels.setText(channels[current]);
        TVChannels.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        TVChannels.setTextSize(20);
        TVChannels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(TVChannels);
           // Create a TextView to house the values
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setId(200 + current);      
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        TVChannels.setTextSize(20);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(valueTV);

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        ChannelTable.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
} /* End of OnCreate*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tags instead of ID's

```
View.setTag()
```

and then to find the view with a certain tag use

```
findViewWithTag()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the difference to the ID's. Is a Tag equivalent to an ID except the fact that it hasn't to be declared in the layout.xml?